# FN+ESC (Reverse Fn) in Asus ux362fa in Debian

Tags: debian, xmodmap, asus

I am trying to set the `fn+esc` to toggle `fn lock` on my **Asus ux362fa** running with Debian 10. Using `xev`, I can confirm that the keycode when I press the `fn+esc` is *keycode 248*. But looking in `xmodmap -pk` command shows me an empty *keysym value* and *keysym name*, thus giving incorrect output.

I made a file `~/.xmodmaprc` which hold:

```
keycode 248 = Fn+Esc
```

But giving me and error upon running `xmodmap .xmodmaprc`:

```
xmodmap:  .xmodmaprc:1:  bad keysym name 'Fn+Esc' in keysym list
```

Also, when running `sudo showkey -k`, I noticed pressing `fn+esc` gives me different keycode which is *keycode 240* and that is a `0x1008ff72 (XF86Reply)` in the list. I can't find keycode for reverse fn. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what you call <kbd>Fn Lock</kbd>. However it is pretty clear that

```
keycode 248 = Fn+Esc
```

will fail as "Fn Lock" is not a valid keysym.

I must add that <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is special as it is handled by the firmware but you can still change the keysyms that are attributed to whatever keycodes the firmware send, if it sends any.

So what you need to do is to find the right keysym you want and attribute it to your keycode 248;

You can find a list of valids keysyms in the file **/usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h**; just truncate the 'XK_' part.
(eg: XK_Backspace is not a valid keysym,
Backspace is a valid keysym)

But it may be possible there is none of the keysyms available will be already bounded to the action you may want perform.

In this case you want to bound a command to your newly attributed keysym on the keycode 248, and how you achieve it easily may mostly depend on the Window Manager you are actually using.

Comment: The mainboard firmware isn't involved in this on modern operating systems, even for other keys.  And Fn is handled within the keyboard itself, and does not pass over the wire.

Answer (score 0):

**`xev`** would show the actual key-symbols. If there is one for ***fn***, it likely is configured as some *modifier*, not a key which you can bind using **`xmodmap`** (except by using the name that **`xev`** identifies).